# dropdown selected value is getting lost when inside a hidden asp:panel

Tags: .net, vb.net, panel

I have web form consisting of a few asp:panels. Only one panel is visible at a time. As the user fills the forms the next panel becomes visible.

In the second panel there is a dropdown list.

I am setting the selectedvalue of the dropdownlist on page load, if not page is postback. However when the second panel becomes visible, the dropdownlist is not preselected.

Everything else is prepopulated except this dropdown list. There are other dropdown lists on other hidden panels, they are also prepopulated appropriately.

Furthermore, if I move the dropdownlist outside the panel, it works as intended, meaning, the selectedvalue is prepopulated.

If I remove the line where all panels are set to visible = false, the dropdownlist gets populated fine.

As soon as I add the code to hide the panels and show them one by one, the selected value is not there.

Here is some code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    ...
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = .Item("city")
    HideAllPanels()
    ...
End Sub

Protected Sub LinkButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButton2.Click
    HideAllPanels()
    Panel2.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I know very little VB, but it appears this line is not formatted correctly: `DropDownList1.SelectedValue = .Item("city")`

Comment: What is your code in HideAllPanels ?

Comment: Hello Ceres, Public Sub HideAllPanels()
        PanelOgrenciKimlikBilgileri.Visible = False
        PanelOgrenciOkulBilgileri.Visible = False
        PanelOgrenciBankaBilgileri.Visible = False
        PanelOgrenciAileDurumu.Visible = False
        PanelOgrenciKardesDurumu.Visible = False
        _myCSS = "display: none"
    End Sub

Comment: This line is new:_myCSS = "display: none" -- I added it as a temp solution to hide the ddl, instead of a asp panel I used an html div